# On the exactness of diagonalisable linear algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

in Herzig's lecture notes on linear algebraic groups (page 24/25, see [https://www.math.toronto.edu/~herzig/lin-alg-groups17-seaton-notes.pdf](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eherzig/lin-alg-groups17-seaton-notes.pdf)), there is a quite interesting fact on the exactness of diagonalisable linear algebraic groups:

Namely that a sequence $0 \to G_1 \to G_2 \to G_3 \to 0$ is exact

if (by definition)

- it is set theoretically exact and
- the induced sequence on Lie algebras $0 \to Lie(G_1)\to Lie(G_2) \to Lie(G_3) \to 0$ is exact.

Note that $G_i$ are linear algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $k$. Furthermore, $X^*(G_i)$ is the group of characters given by Hom$_\text{lin.alg.groups}(G_i,G_{m,k})$ with $G_{m,k}$ the multiplicative group of $k$.

Now it is clear that for diagonalisable groups that the Lie algebras are given by Hom$(X^*(G_i),k)$. However, he now claims the sequence (of Lie algebras, I guess) is exact if and only if

$0 \to X^*(G_3) \to X^*(G_2) \to X^*(G_1) \to 0$ is exact.

I don't see why this should hold; my ideas are the following:

We have that Hom(_,k) is a left-exact contravariant functor, so left exactness should be fine by category theory. However, for the functor to be exact, we need that $X^*(G_1)$ is an injective abelian group.

However, all I can prove is that $X^*(G_1)$ is free and thus projective, however this does not imply that Hom( _ ,k)is exact but rather that Hom(k, _ ) is exact.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez k is the field over which the G_i are linear algebraic groups.

Comment: @max_121 - The "usual" definition of "diagonalizable group" (over a field $k$) is the following: Let $\Gamma$ be an abelian group: Define the Hopf algebra $k[G]$ using the group algebra of $G$ and let $G(\Gamma):=Spec(k[G])$. How do you prove this is equivalent to your definition? It is a good idea to include definitions when you discuss online lecture notes.

Comment: @hm2020 Thanks for the comment! In the context of linear algebraic groups, diagonalizable groups are defined to be closed subgroups of tori, i.e. closed subgroups of $G_{m,k}^n$ for some natural number n. However, there is an anti-equivalence of categories with finite abelian groups (without p-torsion in characteristic p) by taking the coordinate ring (resp. group ring in the other direction). So the  definitions (the one given by you being the natural one in the context of group schemes) are equivalent.